# Next.js - Material Ui responsive drawer - fix re-render of sidebar/logo on page change

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I am using the [responsive drawer](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/) of Material UI in a Next.js project.

I noticed that each time I change page (click on a sidebar link), the logo disappears and re-appears.

This is the implementation of the sidebar:

```
import ListAltIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ListAlt";
import SupervisorAccountIcon from "@mui/icons-material/SupervisorAccount";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemButton from "@mui/material/ListItemButton";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";

import Image from "next/image";
import logo from "../../../assets/logo.svg";
import kitten from "../../../assets/300.jpeg";

import { pages } from "../../../constants";

import StyledLink from "./sidebar.styled";

interface Props {
  handleDrawerToggle?: () => void;
  mobileOpen: boolean;
  drawerWidth: number;
}

const SidebarInner = () => (
  <div>
    <Toolbar>
      <Image
        src={logo}
        alt=" logo"
        width="120"
        height="64"
        className="logo-image"
        style={{ margin: "auto" }}
        priority={true}
      />
    </Toolbar>
    <Divider />
    <List sx={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
      {Object.values(pages).map(({ name, url }, index) => (
        <ListItem key={url} disablePadding>
          <StyledLink href={url}>
            <ListItemButton>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <ListAltIcon /> : <SupervisorAccountIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={name} />
            </ListItemButton>
          </StyledLink>
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
    <Image src={kitten} alt="test image" style={{ margin: "auto" }} />
  </div>
);

export default function Sidebar(props: Props) {
  const { drawerWidth, handleDrawerToggle, mobileOpen } = props;

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Box
        component="nav"
        sx={{ width: { sm: drawerWidth }, flexShrink: { sm: 0 } }}
        aria-label="mailbox folders"
      >
        {/* The implementation can be swapped with js to avoid SEO duplication of links. */}
        <Drawer
          variant="temporary"
          open={mobileOpen}
          onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
          ModalProps={{
            keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
          }}
          sx={{
            display: { xs: "block", sm: "none" },
            "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
              boxSizing: "border-box",
              width: drawerWidth,
            },
          }}
        >
          <SidebarInner />
        </Drawer>
        <Drawer
          variant="permanent"
          sx={{
            display: { xs: "none", sm: "block" },
            "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
              boxSizing: "border-box",
              width: drawerWidth,
            },
          }}
          open
        >
          <SidebarInner />
        </Drawer>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Here is a live [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/next-mui-project-kf7sp6).

Can anyone please help to:

- Understand why the logo re-renders and the kitten below does not re-render
- Fix the logo that disappears for a short time during link change

Answer (score 0):

I forked the sandbox repo and fixed the issue in the `Sidebar.tsx` component which is :

```
import ListAltIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ListAlt";
import SupervisorAccountIcon from "@mui/icons-material/SupervisorAccount";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemButton from "@mui/material/ListItemButton";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";

import Image from "next/image";
import logo from "../../../assets/logo.svg";
import kitten from "../../../assets/300.jpeg";

import { pages } from "../../../constants";

import StyledLink from "./sidebar.styled";

interface Props {
  handleDrawerToggle?: () => void;
  mobileOpen: boolean;
  drawerWidth: number;
}

const svgIcon = () => {
  return (
    <svg width="280" height="80">
      <linearGradient id="lg">
        <stop offset="0%" stopColor="#33ff77" />
        <stop offset="100%" stopColor="#ff4444" />
      </linearGradient>
      <rect
        x="2"
        y="2"
        width="276"
        height="76"
        fill="red"
        stroke={"#555555"}
        strokeWidth={2}
      />
      <text
        x="50%"
        y="50%"
        fontSize="18"
        textAnchor="middle"
        alignmentBaseline="middle"
        fontFamily="monospace, sans-serif"
        fill="#555555"
      >
        280&#215;80
      </text>
    </svg>
  );
};

const SidebarInner = () => (
  <div>
    <Toolbar>
      {svgIcon()}
      <Image
        src={logo}
        alt=" logo"
        width="120"
        height="64"
        className="logo-image"
        style={{ margin: "auto" }}
        priority={true}
      />
    </Toolbar>
    <Divider />
    <List sx={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
      {Object.values(pages).map(({ name, url }, index) => (
        <ListItem key={url} disablePadding>
          <StyledLink href={url}>
            <ListItemButton>
              <ListItemIcon>
                {index % 2 === 0 ? <ListAltIcon /> : <SupervisorAccountIcon />}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={name} />
            </ListItemButton>
          </StyledLink>
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
    <Image src={kitten} alt="test image" style={{ margin: "auto" }} />
  </div>
);

export default function Sidebar(props: Props) {
  const { drawerWidth, handleDrawerToggle, mobileOpen } = props;

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Box
        component="nav"
        sx={{ width: { sm: drawerWidth }, flexShrink: { sm: 0 } }}
        aria-label="mailbox folders"
      >
        {/* The implementation can be swapped with js to avoid SEO duplication of links. */}
        <Drawer
          variant="temporary"
          open={mobileOpen}
          onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
          ModalProps={{
            keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
          }}
          sx={{
            display: { xs: "block", sm: "none" },
            "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
              boxSizing: "border-box",
              width: drawerWidth,
            },
          }}
        >
          <SidebarInner />
        </Drawer>
        <Drawer
          variant="permanent"
          sx={{
            display: { xs: "none", sm: "block" },
            "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
              boxSizing: "border-box",
              width: drawerWidth,
            },
          }}
          open
        >
          <SidebarInner />
        </Drawer>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

As you can see the directly rendered `svg` tag won't re-render on page change , but the one that is used with next's own `<Image />` tag , has issues on page change .

It's the `<Image />` component imported from `next/image` that is having issues re-rending only `svg` format of files . It's suggested to use `svg` files directly in components .